# Sobreescribir método exit() Java clase Thread

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy haciendo un programa y tengo un problema con los hilos en Java.

Tengo este código en una clase extendida de Thread

```
    public void run() {
    try {
        getValues.setAutoDB();
        Connection conn = getValues.getConnection();
        String preparedState = "select " +  column + " from " + table + ";";
        ResultSet resultSet = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(preparedState);

        while(resultSet.next()) {
            values.add(resultSet.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error with DB");
    }
}
```

Funciona bien, pero me tira error ya que un ArrayList (el nombre es values) que tengo está vacío.
Usé el depurador de Visual Studio y me llevó al método exit() de Thread, usé un System.out.println luego de usar values.add(resultSet.getString(1)); y me mostró un valor de la base de datos, pero si usas lo mismo luego de terminar el try catch estos datos ya no existen.
Llegué a la conclusión de que esto pasa debido a que el método exit() de la clase Thread (método privado) elimina todos los datos, algo parecido a un Gargabge Collector. Mi pregunta sería si conocen alguna forma en la que pueda sobreescribir dicho método para dejarlo vacío y que no tenga ese comportamiento. Probé usando @Override pero no sé bien cómo.
Gracias.

Comment: *me tira error ya que un ArrayList (el nombre es values) que tengo está vacío*. ¿Que error te tira? ¿Que tipo de aplicacion estas programando? ¿Estás seguro que cuando se termina este hilo el hilo principal sigue activo? Puede que llames a este hilo desde algun lugar de tu programa, el programa siga su curso con el array vacio y por eso falle. ¿Cómo estás sincronizando tus hilos? Muchos detalles tiene tu pregunta y muy poca información. Echa un vistazo al método `join` de los hilos, vas a tener que llamarlo antes de usar la lista values para asegurar que tengas algo ahi.

Comment: Como dije, capaz no se entendió. En el array quedan guardados los datos hasta que el try catch termina, luego de eso el arraylist se vacía, el error que me tira es ya que en otro lugar uso el método get() de ArrayList y me tira error debido a que está vacío. Y sí, cuando termina este hilo, el hilo principal sigue activo. Y sí, primero llamo ese hilo, luego lo uso. El problema es ese método exit() de la clase Thread, ese método provoca que todos los datos se eliminen, en el propio comentario de dicha clase lo dice